# How to use template functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently doing a program which calculates the scalarProduct (Dot Product) using templates and I've run into a problem with two things.

One being: How to declare a template and call it from main.
Two being: How to pass Arrays to functions.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

```
// scalarProduct.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */

using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
void scalarProduct(T a[], T b[])
{
    T a[3];
    T b[3];

    this->a[] = a;
    this->b[] = b;

    T axb;
    T roota;
    T rootb;
    T result;

    axb = ((a[0] * b[0]) + (a[1] * b[1]) + (a[2] * b[2]));
    roota = sqrt((a[0] * a[0]) + (a[1] * a[1]) + (a[2] * a[2]));    // the formula for the Euclidean length of the vector A.
    rootb = sqrt((b[0] * b[0]) + (b[1] * b[1]) + (b[2] * b[2]));    // the formula for the Euclidean length of the vector B.
    result = axb / roota * rootb;

    cout << "Result: " << result;
};

int main()
{
    int a[3];
    int b[3];

    cout << "Enter A: " << endl;        // Vector A Input
    cout << "X:";
    cin >> a[0];
    cout << "Y:";
    cin >> a[1];
    cout << "Z:";
    cin >> a[2];

    cout << "Ennter B: " << endl;       // Vector B Input
    cout << "X:";
    cin >> b[0];
    cout << "Y:";
    cin >> b[1];
    cout << "Z:";
    cin >> b[2];

    scalarProduct(a[], b[]);


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Probably you can learn some _basic_ C++, then play with templates

Comment: I know how to use C++, I know how templates work, but I don't quite know how to use them.

Comment: You are trying to solve two problems at once. Isolate them, and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: @Kenyanke what you think `scalarProduct(a[], b[]);` does ? what you are up to with usage of `this` ? How to assign/initialize/pass an array in C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with templates, but with C++ basics, like passing array to a function.

```
// scalarProduct.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */

using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
void scalarProduct(T a[], T b[])
{
    /* 
    * remove this
    T a[3];
    T b[3];

    this->a[] = a;
    this->b[] = b;
    */

    T axb;
    T roota;
    T rootb;
    T result;

    axb = ((a[0] * b[0]) + (a[1] * b[1]) + (a[2] * b[2]));
    roota = sqrt((a[0] * a[0]) + (a[1] * a[1]) + (a[2] * a[2]));    // the formula for the Euclidean length of the vector A.
    rootb = sqrt((b[0] * b[0]) + (b[1] * b[1]) + (b[2] * b[2]));    // the formula for the Euclidean length of the vector B.
    result = axb / roota * rootb;

    cout << "Result: " << result;
};

int main()
{
    int a[3];
    int b[3];

    cout << "Enter A: " << endl;        // Vector A Input
    cout << "X:";
    cin >> a[0];
    cout << "Y:";
    cin >> a[1];
    cout << "Z:";
    cin >> a[2];

    cout << "Ennter B: " << endl;       // Vector B Input
    cout << "X:";
    cin >> b[0];
    cout << "Y:";
    cin >> b[1];
    cout << "Z:";
    cin >> b[2];

    //scalarProduct(a[], b[]);
    scalarProduct(a, b);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Also if you dealing with three dimensional points I think it would be a good idea to create `struct Point` or `class Point`. If you want your functions to deal with vectors, then use pointers or *better* `std::vector`.

Comment: Yeah I know about std::vector but the problem I'm solving states I can't use em.

Answer (score 2):

For the template part of the question:

Heres the format for declaring and defining a template function:

```
template<compileTimeParameters>
returnType functionName(functionParameters) {
    ...;
}
```

and invoke it like this:

```
functionName<compileTimeParameters>(functionParameters);
```

For example, if you wanted a function that printed with cout whatever you gave it, go like this:

```
template<typename T>
void println(T value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

and invoke like this:

```
int main() {
    //string
    println<std::string>("yo yo yo print a newline");

    //integer
    println<int>(420);

    //some other random type
    println<myType>(someInstanceOfMyType);

}
```

And if the compiler can deduce the template parameters by the function parameters, you don't have to specify anything explicitly inside the `<>` brackets. For example:

```
int main() {
    //compiler deduces that you are passing a const char[]
    println("the compiler can figure out what I mean");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In scalarProduct() get rid of your local arrays a and b -- you are getting them from the parameters passed into the function.  Also, scalarProduct is a function, not the method of a class, so there is no "this" to reference.

In main() just call:

```
scalarProduct(a, b);
```

It should work then.

Comment: Yeah, the OP doesn't understand some basic concepts which is why his code doesn't work.

Comment: @BWG I've been programming all day, I've ran into errors and fixed them, some I took a break for, this one I took a break but still couldn't think of the answer that's why I came here to ask for someones "help".